# .Net C# Input string was not in a correct format. Trying to insert value into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Here is my C# code:

```
protected void UpdateProduct(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) // ⇦ Gridview products update event
{
    string Tax = (GridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("EditTaxDropDown") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
    string Type = (GridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("EditTypeDropDown") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
    string Id = GridViewProducts.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string Name = (GridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TBName") as TextBox).Text;
    string Description = (GridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TBDescription") as TextBox).Text;
    string Price = (GridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TBPrice") as TextBox).Text;

    string SerialNumber = (GridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TBSerialNumber") as TextBox).Text;

    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        string query = "UPDATE Products SET  Name = @Name, Description = @Description, Price = @Price, type = @type, Tax = @Tax, SerialNumber = @SerialNumber, Meta_Modified = GETDATE() WHERE Id = @Id";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tax", Tax);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", Type);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Price);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNumber", SerialNumber);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            GridViewProducts.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGridData();
            ProductGWBindData(); //refreshes gridview 
        }
    }
}
```

And here is HTML markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" >   
    <ItemTemplate>   
         <asp:Label ID="TBPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:C2}")%>'></asp:Label>     
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>   
         <asp:TextBox  TextMode="Number" step="0.01" ID="TBPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price")%>' ></asp:TextBox>   
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>`
```

As you can see I am interested in `Price` value for some reason I couldn't figure out how to convert string to int, I think It has to do with the decimal "step=0.01" I can pass whole number like 1, 2, 3 ... but not in decimal format 1.00 , 2.00 , 3.01 ...

Please help I was trying all kinds of string to int conversions :(

Comment: `Integer: a number which is not a fraction; a whole number.` - You're storing price as an integer. It is not the correct data type to use to store price, or indeed any number that isn't whole. Money is better stored as a decimal.

Comment: How would you store 3.01 in the Price column when you have `SqlDbType.Int`?

Comment: Change your db type then

Comment: I might suggest also you don't use `Type`, or any keyword as a variable name.

Comment: well thats the thing I was trying it as well with decimal sql type , but always I get " Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the db type to decimal, and declare your price as decimal not string. 
i think your problem is on this code:

```
string Price = (GridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TBPrice") as TextBox).Text
```

change to this :

```
decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal((GridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TBPrice") as TextBox).Text, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

and your command parameter should be like this :

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", Price);
```

I'm not test this code yet, but i think the solution is somewhat similar to this, plz correct me if i am wrong, hope it helps.

Comment: was promising but:   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: it has a problem with the .Value at the end :(

Comment: change to .Text or without extension, hope it helps

Comment: yup did but again: Input string was not in a correct format. :(

Comment: I've added culture info, assuming you used dot to separate the decimal. maybe you also need to debug to see the parameter value on runtime to get better information.

Comment: well now its not trowing error, but it stores just whole number ,for example 1,11 its stored like 1

Comment: have you debug in 'price' parameter? especially when the method being hit, see value on parameter inside, is it already rounded? if it yess, then maybe you need to change the asp file also to match the culture info. try also use dot instead of comma

Comment: I added money sql type to the price column , and now its working good :)